# Closed form solution to consumption-saving model in discrete time

Tags: macroeconomics, consumption, dynamic-programming, dynamic-optimization, saving

Consider the simplest consumption-savings model of the following form:
$$
\max_{\{c_t,a_{t+1}\}_t}\mathbb{E_0}\sum_{t\geq 0} \beta^tu(c_t) \\
a_{t+1} + c_t = (1+r)a_t + y_t \\
y_t \mid y_{t-1} \sim F
$$
The Bellman equation associated is thus
$$
v(a,y)= \max_{c,a'} u(c) + \beta \mathbb{E}[v(a',y') \mid y] \\
a' + c = (1+r)a + y \\
y' \mid y\sim F 
$$
I know how to derive the Euler equation and how to use algorythms to numerically find the optimal policies $c(a,y)$ and $a'(a,y)$. I wanted to know what are the known and most used closed form solutions for these policies, that is which utility $u$ and income distribution $F$ generates a tractable form for $c(a,y)$ and $a'(a,y)$.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe Brock and Mirman (1972) and Hercowitz Sampson (1991) both have closed form solutions to their optimal growth problems.